# VueJS Windows Authentication against ASP.NET Core 5 Docker API not appearing

Tags: docker, vue.js, asp.net-core, active-directory, windows-authentication

**Setup:**
We have setup on our windows VM (on-premises) to run docker (windows container) + gMSA / service account for our ASP.NET Core 5 API - internally running on Kestrel with `.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();` (NOT IIS). It authenticates well as the configured service account e.g. against MSSQL or the File Server.
If I open up any protected endpoint its using my windows credentials or is asking me (if not on a domain joined computer). The user test endpoint return the windows users claims.

This just the API which works fine!

**Issue:**
The "issue" is, that our VueJS application is running in a docker container (linux containers) on a linux host - inside hosted via nginx. Same network. After opening the UI the first time (without having opened the API) no authentication request is happening. The interesting part is: After opening the API the first time and entering windows credentials and then opening the UI works and shows the use/claims (which we return from the backend).

In the frontend we are using axios with `withCredentials: true`.

**Question:**
What must be done to enable the UI to negotiate the windows login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reverse proxy that's passing requests to your container must have NTLM support enabled for Windows authentication to work. IIS supports this by default, but for others, you need to activate it manually. This must be repeated down the proxy chain.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio):

> Credentials can be persisted across requests on a connection. Negotiate authentication must not be used with proxies unless the proxy maintains a 1:1 connection affinity (a persistent connection) with Kestrel.

See the docs for your reverse proxy:

- nginx: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#ntlm
- caddy: https://github.com/caddyserver/ntlm-transport

Comment: Guess I overlooked that :( thanks I will try and come back

Comment: That would have been the solution, saidly the ntlm flag is only available for nginx-plus / commercial version :( thanks again

Comment: Yeah. A more universal but convoluted solution could be running an IdentityServer on IIS (or anything that supports NTLM) somewhere, and delegate auth to that app. Even if the UI doesn't automatically log you in, you get redirected to IdServer which recognizes the domain account, logs you in and redirects you back to the Vue app with a token that your backend can verify.